# Passing data from client to server using node.js + socket.io + express/ejs

Tags: node.js, heroku, express, socket.io, ejs

I'm trying to figure out how to access data from the front end of a node.js + socket.io app. Using the "heroku logs --tail" (live logging), I get an instant response after I put something in the input and hit submit:

```
debug: xhr-polling received data packet 5:::{"name":"data","args":[{"hash":"<whatever I put in the input"}]}
```

But I'm unable to access it to log it. The console.log line below is never even executed.

Heres by backend server.js

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.render('index.ejs', {
  layout:false,
  locals: {
    someVariable: "blah"
  }
});

// Get Form Data
io.sockets.on('data', function(data) {
  console.log("heres the hash " + data.hash);
});
```

And this in my front end

```
<form>
        <span class="label">#</span><input type="text" name="hashtag" id="hashtag" placeholder="hashtag">
        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Roll em in!">
</form>

<script>
var socket = io.connect();
$('#submit').on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  alert('clicked!');
  socket.emit('data', {
    hash: $('#hashtag').val()
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: does your client's `io.connect()` actually have the server address and port?

Comment: Yes everything else in the app works, it's just a lot to paste, I just pasted the necessary snippets. Here's the top of my script:

var util = require('util'),
    http = require('http'),
    express = require('express'),
    ejs = require('ejs'),
    app = express();

  var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
  var server = app.listen(port);
  var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

// for heroku
  io.configure(function () { 
    io.set("transports", ["xhr-polling"]); 
    io.set("polling duration", 10); 
  });

Comment: Didn't realize it would paste without returns, new here, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about doing it like this:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
  socket.on('data', function(data){
    console.log("heres the hash " + data.hash);
    });
});
```